# Use OpenCV bounding box coordinates in pointcloud

Tags: python, opencv, ros, open3d

I'm developing a ROS project with a robotic arm which should pick some fragments from the table and put them in boxes.
I get an RGB image from a Intel RealSense D415 camera, load it in my OpenCV/CNN pipeline which segments the fragments/instances in the image, get the coordinates of the centroid and of the bounding box of each instance/fragment and, through the CNN, classifies each of them giving a label.
Then each fragment is spawned in the Gazebo/ROS simulation using the information above (centroid of the sherd and bounding box) and the arm will try to grasp the fragments.
I'd like to use the OpenCV 2D bounding box to locate the fragment also in the pointcloud so I can use some deep grasp methon (e.g. Grasp Pose Detecetion GPD) to get the end effector oriented for a correct grasp, how should I match the 2D bounding boxes with the pointcloud to get the same fragment/object?

This is my segmentation code which creates the bounding boxes

```
for c in segmentation.cnts:
        # if the contour is not sufficiently large, ignore it
        if cv2.contourArea(c) < 100:
            continue

        # compute the rotated bounding box of the contour
        orig = segmentation.thresholded.copy()
        box = cv2.minAreaRect(c)
        box = cv2.cv.BoxPoints(box) if imutils.is_cv2() else cv2.boxPoints(box)
        box = np.array(box, dtype="int")
        # print(f'BoxPoint are {box}')
        # print(f'BoxPoints for the x are {box[:,0]}')
        # print(f'BoxPoints for the x are {box[:,1]}')
        
        #Store extreme coordinates of the box
        x_min, y_min = np.amin(box[:,0]), np.amin(box[:,1])
        x_max, y_max = np.amax(box[:,0]), np.amax(box[:,1])
        # print(f'x_min is {x_min}, x_max is {x_max}')
        # print(f'y_min is {y_min}, y_max is {y_max}')

        box = perspective.order_points(box)

        # unpack the ordered bounding box, then compute the midpoint
        # between the top-left and top-right coordinates, followed by
        # the midpoint between bottom-left and bottom-right coordinates
        (tl, tr, br, bl) = box
        (tlX, tlY) = tl
        (trX, trY) = tr
        (brX, brY) = br
        (blX, blY) = bl
        # print((tl, tr, br, bl))
        (tltrX, tltrY) = segmentation.midpoint(tl, tr)
        (blbrX, blbrY) = segmentation.midpoint(bl, br)
        # compute the midpoint between the top-left and top-right points,
        # followed by the midpoint between the top-righ and bottom-right
        (tlblX, tlblY) = segmentation.midpoint(tl, bl)
        (trbrX, trbrY) = segmentation.midpoint(tr, br)
        #compute the midpoint between diagonal ((top-left, bottom-right), (bottom-left, top-right))
        (tlbrX, tlbrY) = segmentation.midpoint(tl, br)
        print(f'Center of sherd is {(tlbrX, tlbrY)}')
        segmentation.x_center = (tlbrX, tlbrY)[0]
        segmentation.y_center = (tlbrX, tlbrY)[1]

        # compute the Euclidean distance between the midpoints
        dA = dist.euclidean((tltrX, tltrY), (blbrX, blbrY))
        dB = dist.euclidean((tlblX, tlblY), (trbrX, trbrY))
        
        # if the pixels per metric has not been initialized, then
        # compute it as the ratio of pixels to supplied metric
        # (in this case, mm)
        if segmentation.pixelsPerMetric is None:
            segmentation.pixelsPerMetric = dB / segmentation.width

        # compute the size of the object
        dimA = dA / segmentation.pixelsPerMetric
        dimB = dB / segmentation.pixelsPerMetric
        
        # n = n+1
        # if n > 0: #n == 0 is the measure specimen, no extraction and no prediction
        #uses the extreme coordinate of the box to extract the fragment as a ROI (Region Of Interest)
        segmentation.ROI = segmentation.thresholded[y_min:y_max, x_min:x_max]
        
        segmentation.regint()

        # RosPub.print_coord(segmentation.x_center, segmentation.y_center)
    

        if n > 0:
            segmentation.infer()
        
            # distance of center of sherd from image origin
            centX = segmentation.x_center / segmentation.pixelsPerMetric
            centY = segmentation.y_center / segmentation.pixelsPerMetric
            print(f"Center of sherds from origin in mm is {centX}, {centY}")
            position_mm = open(position_file, "a")
            conf = repr(segmentation.confidence)
            lab = repr(segmentation.prediction)
            class_sherd = ("class" + lab)
            x_mm = repr(round(centX,2))
            y_mm = repr(round(centY,2))
            nome = ("sherd_" + str(n))
            position_mm.write(lab + " " + conf + " " + x_mm + " " + y_mm + " " + nome + "\n")
            position_mm.close()
            
            # segmentation.add_link(x_mm, y_mm)
            
            segmentation.model_creation(dimA, dimB, n, class_sherd)
            
            RosPub.add_link(nome, n, (centX/1000), (centY/1000))
            
            if im_ch == "y":
                segmentation.image_show(orig, box, dimA, dimB, tltrX, tltrY,\
                     trbrX, trbrY, blbrX, blbrY, tlblX, tlblY, blX, blY, brX, brY,  nome)        

        segmentation.ROI_number += 1
        n += 1
```

Comment: Hi! You should probably ask this question on [Robotics Stack Exchange](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/).
Anyway, you have to first verify the `height` and `width` of your [sensor_msgs/PointCloud2](https://docs.ros.org/en/melodic/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/PointCloud2.html) message. If `height` is different from 1, then you have a point cloud with a 2D image-like structure, and you can use the vertexes of the 2D bounding box to extract the relevant part of the point cloud. If not, you should back-project the cloud to the camera plane using the intrinsic matrix to find the region you need.

Comment: Thanks, I got that "PointCloud height is 720" from PointCloud2 message, so I think it's an ordered pcl, I'll try to use 2d bounding box coordinates to see what I get...

Comment: Perfect! If you manage to get what you are looking for, please post it as answer to the post for future readers